# Cannot read property 'getCurrentAccessToken' of undefined

Tags: react-native, facebook-access-token, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

It seems like AccessToken is undefined in my code

```
    import {AccessToken} from 'react-native-fbsdk';
 AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                                        (data) => {....}).catch(e => {
            console.log('fb could not connect because: ' + e);
        })
```

catch is being invoked.
I am using `"react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.1"`

my device : iOS simulator - iphone62 - iOS 12

my Podfile:

```
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'Bolts'
```

Comment: Can you share full logs?